# Unable to route from one web page to other page in an application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I have been trying to route from one web page to other web pages with the help of nodejs express, HTML, and MongoDB. But unable to route the page. I a, following GitHub link to develop the application.
I have analyzed the code using some references.
I am providing the code.

GitHub & reference link: https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/nodejs-basics-tutorial/tree/master/09-mongodb

Code:

```
routing link
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="./home.hbs">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#index">Registration</a></li>
    <li><a href="./event_schedule.hbs">Event Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a href="./event_guidelines.hbs">Event Guidelines</a></li>
    <li><a href="./contact_details.hbs">Contact Details</a></li>
</ul>
```

Routing link in index.js

```
router.get('/registration', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("kumari1");
  res.render('event_schedule');
});
```

Kindly help me out of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't provide link to template page like this ....

waht you want to do is :

create new routes which will serve your template pages.

So you'll have something like this :

`router.get("/contact",(req,res)=>{res.render("contact-detail.hbs)});` and this for all your template pages.

then in your routing link file `<a href="/contact">Contact >Details</a>`

Comment: thanks for your reply... it worked out well...learned to give the routing links...